# How do I duplicate a PDF with some text replacement and redaction

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, itext, itext7

I am exploring couple of third party components to work with PDF through C#. These are Aspose.pdf.net and iTextSharp. Following are the details about what I am exploring them for:

I have some PDFs that contain sensitive information in form of text, like name of person, city, etc. 
These PDFs need to be duplicated into another copy but while creating duplicated copy, sensitive text needs to be searched & replaced with some dummy text. The replacement is essential to avoid tracing original information, by any fraudulent means. 
Also, the replaced text requires to be redacted.

Finding text is expected to support RegEx, as there could be variations of text that needs to be masked.

Could you please assist me how can this be done using iTextShart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iTextSharp is capable of complete redaction(both visual as well as the data stored in the pdf) using the PdfSweep module (http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfsweep). I'll write up an answer providing more detail

Comment: @Jaqen - Is Samuel's answer an option for you or are you looking for something different. As you neither accepted that answer nor in a comment or by an edit of your question indicated in which way that answer might not suffice, it's difficult to help you any further.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, I've added comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTextSharp is capable of complete redaction(both visual as well as the data stored in the pdf) using the PdfSweep module (http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfsweep). 
In order to have the redaction happen after text search you'd have to:

1. Extract the text from the document (can be done using iText).
2. Search through the extracted text and obtain the positions of the text you want redacted. (needs an implementation from your side)
3. Use these positions to define where PdfSweep has to redact. (a couple of lines of code)

By default, PdfSweep visualy redacts by drawing coloured bars over the locations, and internally removes the text and any image.
While it is technically possible to use iText to fill the redacted positions with some dummy text, the implementation thereof has a number of pitfalls.

PdfSweep is closed source module for iText7, you can contact our sales team for more information on the licensing.

Comment: Thanks Samuel for the feedback. I downloaded trial version for iText7 for .net. But i didn't find any way to use PdfSweep. Does it need to be downloaded separately? Please assist.

Comment: PdfSweep is a closed source module that requires a separate license. Right now, we don't have a trial version for it in the same way as we do for iText7 core, but you can get in touch with our sales department through here:
http://itextpdf.com/request-a-quote

Comment: We're looking for how this search-replace-redact can be done through some third party components' trial versions available for working with PDF; and then we've to decide which suits to our requirements. Can this be done using some other trial versions available for iText? Please suggest.